# Trusty's first login keyboard cheat-sheet: Can I see it again?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, login, 14.04

After upgrade to 14.04 trusty I got a nice "cheat sheet" for unity keyboard shortcuts.

I saw it briefly after login. Changing the display brightness on my laptop made it disappear already.

Can I see that exact window with the shortcuts again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press and hold the <kbd>Super</kbd> key for a second. That would display all the default shortcuts available in Unity. In fact, it also lists the shortcut to display all the shortcuts :-)

[image: Unity Shortcuts]

This also opens the launcher, meaning, the application icons in the sidebar launcher would be numbered and you may press any of the displayed numbers to open the respective application.